# Centering with ImageMapster

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image that uses imagemapster wrapped in a div, but the div won't center for some reason. If I remove all the JS code, the div centers, so it's definitely due to the image mapster stuff.

It's quite simple, just:

```
<div class="chartmap">
    <img id="waterfall" align="middle" src="http://i1372.photobucket.com/albums/ag358/rls462/waterfall_zpsdd7cc432.png" usemap="#water" alt="Waterfall Methodology Map">
    <map name="water">
        <area ......>

         ...
    </map>
</div>
```

here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/stamblerre/t6K8X/13/

Any thoughts? Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when initializing Mapster on an img element, jQuery wraps the image with a dynamic container thats aligned to the left by default.
you would want to re-align the dynamic container to the center:

`$('#waterfall')` is your image, so to access the wrapping container you need to call `$('#waterfall').parent()`
and then align it: `.css({"margin":"0 auto"})`

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#waterfall').mapster({
         singleSelect: true,
         clickNavigate: true,
         scaleMap: false,
         fill: false,
         stroke: true,
         strokeColor: '000080',
         strokeWidth: 3,
         mapKey: 'data-name',
     }).parent().css({"margin":"0 auto"});
 });
```

here is your fixed <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/t6K8X/15/)**</kbd>